# Can i get back which was git cleaned?

Tags: git-clean

I just cleaned a file while exploring cleaning option in git.
How can i get that file back ?

I used below command:
git clean path/file_01.py -i

Then i selected:
    4: ask each

Finally, presseed 'y' instead 'N'
    yes

Comment: The file is deleted, and by definition of `clean`, it is not tracked by `git`. Look for general guides on how to undelete files on your OS, this has nothing to do with `git` any more.

Answer (score 0):

`git clean` only removes files that aren't tracked by git in the first place, so there's no git-trick that can recover such a file once it's gone.

Comment: Are they files deleted from disk as well ?
Can i get those in local repo or recycle bin ?

Comment: @JayadevBS `git clean` will delete files from the disk. Whether or not they remain in your recycle bin is up to the OS you're using. I just test with Git Bash on Windows 10, they do not.